# Accessing Chatter API using JavaScript (same origin issue)?

Tags: javascript, api, salesforce, same-origin-policy, salesforce-chatter

I am trying to access the Chatter API from JavaScript that is running on localhost (and will eventually be hosted somewhere). If I try a normal AJAX GET request, I get the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

I have tried the Salesforce [AJAX toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/) but it seems that needs to be run from a Force.com domain. I cannot use JSONP because the Chatter API only returns JSON.

Does anyone know of a common workaround for my situation? Something equivalent to the LinkedIn JavaScript API for example?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/document/#chatter-api) and also you need to setup a [proxy](https://github.com/jsforce/jsforce-ajax-proxy) to fix the CORS problem.